# "The specified network password is not correct" exception in X509Certificate2 constructor

Tags: c#, exception, certificate

I have a console application which loads an X509 Certificate from a byte array as follows:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certificateContent,      // byte[]
                                password,                // string
                                X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

`certificateContent` is a `byte[]` representing the contents of a pfx file.  This code works fine for a number of certificates I've tested.  There is one certificate I'm testing, though, that causes this line to throw a `CryptographicException` with the message "The specified network password is not correct.", even though the password provided is correct.

The weird part is that I can use the same code in LinqPad to create a certificate from the same pfx file with the same password, and it works okay.

I've checked the call site in the console application in the debugger, and verified that the correct values are being passed in.

What could cause this constructor to throw this exception in a console app, but not in LinqPad using the same data, and work fine in both places for other certificates?

**More Details**

The certificates are stored in a database in Base64.  The Console app reads the certificate from the DB, converts it from Base64 to a byte[], and then tries to create the `X509Certificate2` object as above.

There are three certificates I've been testing with:

1. My personal Client Authentication certificate provided by my employer's CA.
2. A test certificate created by a colleague using his own self-signed CA.
3. My own test certificate created by myself using a self-signed CA.

Certificates 1 and 2 work as expected in both the console app and LinqPad.

Certificate 3 loads fine in LinqPad, but generates the error above if I try to use it in the console app.

There are two significant differences between certs 2 & 3.

1. Cert2 expires in 2016 and Cert3 expires in 2039
2. The private key associated with cert2 is 2048 bit.  Cert3 is 1024 bits.

Could either of these differences result in the "specified network password is not correct" error?  And why would all 3 certs work fine in LinqPad, but only 1 throw the error in the Console app?

Comment: Is the certificate/private key for the certificate in question already installed in CertMgr.msc? Which OS are you using? Does your app target the same .NET Framework version that LinqPad is running in?

Comment: Have you installed the certificate on the machine ?

Comment: Is Linqpad and your app running with the same credentials? Including running as elevated? You need to have elevated to access the certificate store in code I believe.

Comment: @ericlaw - The cert/private key is installed in certmgr.msc.  Windows 8.  The application and LinqPad are both running in .Net 4.0.

Comment: @MikeCheel - Yes, both are running under my account, which has admin rights on the machine.  I've tried running elevated and not elevated with the same results.  The other certs I've tested work fine when running non-elevated, and LinqPad is not running elevated but works fine for this problem certificate.

Comment: What about trying with MachineKeySet (or MachineKeySet | PersistKeySet)

Comment: Do you know which CSP provider was used to store the key? I'd previously hit an error message like this due to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/04/30/default-provider-type-for-cspparameters-has-changed.aspx

Comment: @MikeCheel - MachineKeySet doesn't help.

Comment: At this point I would want to know more about environment and the code.

Comment: @MikeCheel - I've added some more details about the app and the certs I'm testing with.  I'm not sure how much more I can tell you about the code.

Comment: It *sounds* permissions related. I don't think it is the permissions to the private keys though because usually when its that I get the 'key set not found error'. Since it sounds like your self signed cert is something you have control over have you tried regenerating it with the same bitness ? (2048)

Comment: @MikeCheel - Not yet.  I have a work-around at the moment, and other priorities.  I'll try regenerating the cert at some stage and let you know the result.

Comment: Please do as I am interested in your resolution. And what is the work around?

Comment: @MikeCheel using `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` fixed this problem for me, thanks!

Comment: So you were opening from the user store instead it appears. Good to hear you solved it.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28212527/130352 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8286110/130352

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a self-signed certificate which I exported through MMC (microsoft management console) with a password. Loading this certificate went fine on my own machine (win10), but gave the exception with message "The specified network password is not correct" on a server machine (not win10).

What solved it in my case? When I exported the certificate I set a password using AES256-SHA256, but this certificate encryption was not supported on the server machine (after reading this [dotnet runtime issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23437#issuecomment-328564395)). When I changed it to TripleDES-SHA1 it worked fine locally and on the server as well.

Quote from the [dotnet runtime issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23437#issuecomment-328564395):

> WindowsCryptographicException: An internal error occurred probably means that PFXImportCertStore failed, returning null and calling SetLastError with NTE_FAIL.
>
> Things that I'd speculate can cause it:
>
> - The PFX was created with a different encryption password and
>   integrity password, and the integrity password is what was provided
>   to the constructor. But that wouldn't be the case if the same PFX
>   file works on any Windows machine.
> - The PFX was created using the
>   PKCS12_PROTECT_TO_DOMAIN_SIDS and there's some sort of problem
>   talking to AD on the other side. I don't think we support this kind
>   of PFX. The PFX was generated using the guidance from
>   https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292#appendix-B, namely, to use
>   PBES2+PBKDF2 for encrypting the private keys instead of
>   pbeWithSHAAnd3-KeyTripleDES-CBC In this case, the PFX will open on
>   Windows 10, but not prior versions. (At least, I think that's the
>   behavior I recall hitting with this case). It also, IIRC, won't open
>   on macOS.
> - PKCS#12 v1.1 also talks about encrypting and/or signing a
>   PFX using asymmetric cryptography rather than a password-based
>   scheme. But I don't know if even Win10 supports that, since I don't
>   see any controls for it in PFXExportCertStoreEx. So the only thing
>   that I can quickly think of that makes sense is you have a "new" PFX
>   and your test environment is Windows 10, but your production
>   environment is Win2012R2.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will help somebody:

[User "S C"](http://wald.intevation.de/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1219&forum_id=21&group_id=11) points out the following requirement for certificate passwords on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

```
0 < password.Length < 32
```

I have seen conflicting reports on whether 32 is allowed. I can confirm that I was using a 32 character password (an MD5 hash), and truncating it to 30 characters fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, was banging my head with a 40 char password... why does Windows even allow you to export it...

Answer (score 0):

According to [uGeeen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631386/trouble-installing-certificate-from-pfx-file) here, certificates created on Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP should have a password, or they will throw this exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function sign(keystore As String, level As Integer, src As String, name As String,dest As String, sig As String, pass As String)

        'Dim store As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store = New System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store
        'store.Open(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
        'Dim sel As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection

        ' If sig <> "" And pass <> "" Then
        Try


            Dim y As Int16 = 200
            ' For i As Integer = 0 To sel.Count - 1
            Dim pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(src)
            Dim signedPdf = New FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)
            Try
                Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(sig, pass)

                Dim cp As Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser = New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser()
                Dim chain As Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() = New Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate() {cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData)}




                Dim stamper As PdfStamper
                stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, "0"c, Nothing, True)
                Dim signatureAppearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance
                'signatureAppearance.SignatureGraphic = Image.GetInstance(pathToSignatureImage)
                signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(name)

                signatureAppearance.CertificationLevel = level
                Dim externalSignature As IExternalSignature = New X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1")
                ' Dim digest As IExternalSignature = New BouncyCastleDigest
                ' signatureAppearance.s 
                'signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(New Rectangle(50,50,50,
                signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION
                MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES)
                ' MakeSignature. 



            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox("Signature File Password is not correct for the user Id :" & error_userid)
                'Exit Function
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        ' End If
        Return 0
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(rootPath, "cert.pfx");

if(!File.Exists(fileName)) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Signing Certificate is missing!");
}

var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName,"123456789");
```

where "123456789" is my password